# Firefox with Firebug Sometimes Hangs in JSON Calls

Tags: firefox, script, firebug

Please see this: http://gisdev.clemson.edu/fireflies/
On my Windows 7 machine with Firefox 29 if I click on the year 2013 radio button (toward top right) then Firefox **sometimes** hangs and gives a message like: 'Stop running script' or 'continue' or 'debug'. This problem happens only on my machine's Firefox; in other machine's Firefox no such problem.

I understand that the call to the 2013 data loads some larger data but that data is only about 79 kb of text. The only thing I can think of is that I have Firebug installed and that may be causing some problem.

I'd like to fix this problem because Firefox is my main test browser.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with that site in that it doesn't cache the data which is very wasteful and slow since JQuery is having to actually fetch and presumably process the whole JSON every time. However, as you say it is only less than 80k.

I can't see a problem on mine and a quick check didn't reveal any other issues.

My first thought would be a addon since Firefox issues are nearly always caused by addons doing something they shouldn't or exhibiting unexpected behaviours.

Comment: Cache? I think the I will have to call the json function every time to load data--and data is 'real time'. The round map markers are being cached though. I also checked on my home machine's Firefox 29 with Firebug 1.12x and that had no issues. Oh, good idea about the Add-on--I will see if disabling some can help. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, hope it helps. The data didn't look particularly live as it is limited to a whole year so I would think that, for most purposes, a cache timeout of around a week maybe even a month wouldn't really be noticeable. Then you would only need to process the JSON if it changed.

Comment: The 2013 data is legacy but I don't know how to cache that through some postgresql/json way. The 2014 is live and will probably start to get frequent updates when this project launches. BTW, Firefox crashes only when Firebug is enabled. I have just disabled ('Ask to Activate') every Plugin

Comment: I'd ask the caching question in Stack Overflow, I imagine that you have a PHP handler or something similar that can do the job. Re the crash, I assume you have the latest updates? FB is usually pretty solid.

Comment: Firebug is 1.12.8 and I assume is the latest one (got upgraded when FF got upgraded to 29). Here is some more info: My FF is setup to clear cache upon close. So when I launch a new FF window, launch FB, and then click on 2013 that's when crash happens--almost always. But when I launch a new FF window, click on 2013 and then launch FB then no problem! I think I can learn to live with this.

Comment: I'd report a bug to FB. Any reason to clear the cache on close?

Comment: I clear the cache for no real valid reason except that this is a developer environment and I'd like to see latest image or css etc changes rapidly; most things load from local files and local web/database server and so not much of an overhead.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with FF 29 + FB 1.12.8 on WinXP. If you believe it's a problem with Firebug, [try out Firebug 2.0](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/) (currently in beta phase; requires FF 30+). It switched to a new debugging API, which may fix your problem.